# bind constant by program/class with gwt/gin

Tags: gwt, constants, gwt-gin

How can the constant be bound by program/class with gwt/gin?

Instead of:

bindConstant().annotatedWith(AString.class).to("XYZ");

We need: ( Obviously, it doesn't compile )

bindConstant().annotatedWith(AString.class).to(CustomStringProvider.class);

Because this constant is stored in cookie/offline storage.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply `bind(String.class).annotatedWith(AString.class).toProvider(CustomStringProvider.class)`?

If you have a provider, it's obviously not a *constant*.

Comment: I like this idea. What does this "CustomStringProvider" look like?

Comment: Er, the same as the one you'd have liked to use with `bindConstant()`? I use `@Provides` methods for a bunch of strings and it works very well, even using JSNI: `@Provides @AString native String provideAString() /*-{ return $wnd.aString; }-*/;` There's no reason you couldn't do this with a `Provider<String>`

Comment: I see error of "[ERROR] Instance binding not supported;" for "@Provides native String xyz()"

Comment: Hmm, probably unrelated: I'm using this with GIN 1.5.0 and Guice 3.0 (this is a real copy/paste from my code): `@Provides
  @CurrentUser
  native String provideUsername() /*-{
    return $wnd.user.userName;
  }-*/;`

Comment: I don't understand "@CurrentUser" and "provideUsername", I was using the same ID, @AString and provideAString(). What are these two here? Thanks!

Comment: CurrentUser is a custom binding annotation (just like your AString), the method name doesn't matter.